# PhoneGap android database not working

Tags: android, database, html, jquery-mobile, cordova

I'm having problems doing the Database example from PhoneGap. http://docs.phonegap.com/phonegap_storage_storage.md.html#openDatabase

The Problem is, when i run the example to openDatabase and populates he retrieves me the the Success Alert, but when i try to do the select one it gives me an error:

```
"Error processing SQL:0"
```

Is there any issue with databases and the android phone that i don't know? I've tried also in the android's emulator and i'm keep getting the same issue.

Can you help me?

Here is the javascript code:

Now i have the following code:

```
   document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

function populateDB(tx) {
    tx.executeSql('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS DEMO');
    tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS DEMO (id unique, data)');
    tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO DEMO (id, data) VALUES (1, "First row")');
    tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO DEMO (id, data) VALUES (2, "Second row")');
}

function errorCB(err) {
    alert("Error processing SQL: " + err.code);
}

function successCB() {
    alert("success!");
}

function queryDB(tx) {
    tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM DEMO', [], querySuccess, errorCB);
}

function querySuccess(tx, results) {
    alert("i'm here =)");
}

function querySuccess(tx, results) {
    // this will be empty since no rows were inserted.
    console.log("Insert ID = " + results.insertId);
    // this will be 0 since it is a select statement
    console.log("Rows Affected = " + results.rowAffected);
    // the number of rows returned by the select statement
    console.log("Insert ID = " + results.rows.length);
}

function onDeviceReady() {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#submit').click(function() {
            alert('clicked');
            var db = window.openDatabase("test", "1.0", "Test DB", 1000000);
            db.transaction(populateDB, errorCB, successCB);
            db.transaction(queryDB, errorCB);
        })
    });
}
```

And still have the Succes alert when i do the populate transaction but the Alert of the queryDB has the Error processing SQL:0.

Thanks in advance,
Elkas
PS: I'm also using jQuery Mobile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Forgot to update this question. With Lion 10.7.2 its working perfectly.

Regards,

Elkas

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if phonegap is ready:

document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

Comment: Sorry mate. Didn't solve it. Still have the alert of the succes in the datanaseOpen and the Error processing SQL:0 when i try the Select query.

Comment: I'll chabge the code from the post above. For the the one i have now.

Comment: you are using function querySuccess(tx, results) twice in javascript there is no overload function either deletel first function

Answer (score 0):

I just made it. It seems that was a problem of operative system. I made a downgrade to the operative system and now the system works perfectly.

BTW, i had OS X Lion and now OS X Snow Leopard. Maybe the problem wasn't the OS but fixed it for now. When the 10.7.2 comes out I'll upgrade again and give here a reply if its working.

Regards,
Elkas